# How to use status like is in Postma from code , when this status is not present in response

Tags: typescript, https, nativescript, response, status

Service.ts

From this function I get like response a JSON like below:

```
public signupuser(user: Users): Observable<boolean> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let body = user;
    return this.http.post(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.signup), body, {
    })
        .pipe(map((response: Response) => {
            console.log('response', response)
            return true;
        }));
}
```

JSON:

```
 response {
  "email": "usertest@gmail.com",
  "nome": "user",
  "cognome": "test",
  "abbonato": 0,
  "cityid": "22",
  "msg": "Registered correctly."
  }
```

When I use it from Postman I get and status 200 OK or any status error

[image]

My question is: How to use this status from code, When this status code is not present in JSON file? Or any idea  please?

Any idea please?

Update:

How to read and X-JWT that is in header like in [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code I believe you are using Angular, by default HttpClient observes the body not response. You will have to set the `observe` attribute in the options to `response` then you should be able to read the status.

```
public signupuser(user: Users): Observable<boolean> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let body = user;
    return this.http.post(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.signup), body, { observe: 'response' })
        .pipe(map((response: HttpResponse) => {
            console.log('response', response);
            return true;
        }));
}
```

Comment: Generic type 'HttpResponse<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)
???

Comment: Where you are importing HttpResponse from?

Comment: import { HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: Only I change it like this `(response: HttpResponse<any>)`

Comment: I don't see any issues on my end, if you still see the typings issue you may share the Playground Sample. Moreover `response` will be of known type by the return value of post method, you don't have to explicitly declare the type.

Comment: For me work. Please, in this function show all correct, only X-JWT is null. When I use import from Http, and `console.log(response.headers.get('X-JWT'));` in my function (in question) show correct X-JWT. How to call it in your function please?

Comment: Response headers should have worked if server is returning it. Without the endpoint or a testable Playground I can't comment on it much.

Comment: Hey Manoj, How are you? Please can you see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57427431/how-to-use-httpclient-using-get-method-when-token-set-in-the-header Your answers are always correct. Thank you!