# How to use httpClient using get method when token set in the header

Tags: typescript, https, nativescript, response

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57371989/how-to-use-status-like-is-in-postma-from-code-when-this-status-is-not-present/57376702?noredirect=1#comment101241591_57376702) I get correct answer for problem.

Now I want to use it in get method and I want to send also in header token.

I modify it like below:

```
 public detailsuser(): Observable<Users[]> {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('X-Token', this.currentUser.token);
        return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.details), { headers: headers },{ observe: 'response' })
            .pipe(map((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
                console.log('response', response);
                return response.body.map(data => {
                    console.log(data)
                    return new Users(data);
                });
            }));
    }
```

In `{observe: 'response'}` show this error

> (property) observe: string Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.

Have you any idea please?

**solved :**

```
public detailsuser(): Observable<Users[]> {
            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            headers.append('X-Token', this.currentUser.token);
            return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.details), 
           {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({'X-Token': this.currentUser.token}),
            observe: 'response'
           })
                .pipe(map((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
                    console.log('response', response);
                    return response.body.map(data => {
                        console.log(data)
                        return new Users(data);
                    });
                }));
        }
```

Comment: Checkout the documentation / typescript declarations. GET request takes only 2 params, the second options param holds both headers and observe.

Comment: I try `{headers ,observe: 'response'}`  and show `Argument of type '{ headers: Headers; observe: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'observe' does not exist in type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.ts(2345)`

Comment: I solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Manoj, have you any idea, why this solution doesn't work in IOS?

Comment: Please share Playground sample of whatever issue you are seeing.

Comment: i can't create a playground project. 
I run app in Iphone 6. Communicate with backend is in `https` Error is in screenshot like in post. Thank you for your help!